# mod_pagespeed not compressing images

Tags: page-speed

`mod_pagespeed` is not compressing images on my homepage.

My current config has:

```
AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
```

What is the usual setting people use for `mod_pagespeed` to get all the CSS, images, JS, etc. benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the because the images weren't cacheable due to some headers pagespeed would not process the images. Make sure the images are cacheable.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq

> Your resources (images, css, javascript) aren't cacheable. If
>   PageSpeed sees cache-control headers such as nocache or private it
>   will not rewrite the resources.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer i am facing same problem i have searched through web but dint got any solution in this answer what you are trying to say really your answer will be appreciated i have spent more than 8 days to resolve this issue hope you will provide something good.

Answer (score 0):

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters move_css_to_head,move_css_above_scripts
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments,collapse_whitespace
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript,convert_jpeg_to_webp
```